# Spring Boot and EhCache 3 not working on Service layer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching, ehcache-3

I am implementing Ehcache with a simple use case and I'm unable to make it work on @Service layer. I'm not sure whats wrong.

This is my Service class:

```
@Service
public class AccountsServiceImpl implements AccountsService {

    private final AccountsRepository reactiveAccountsRepository;


    @Autowired
    public AccountsServiceImpl(AccountsRepository reactiveAccountsRepository){
        this.reactiveAccountsRepository = reactiveAccountsRepository;
    }

    @Override
    @Cacheable(value = "accounts", key = "#root.methodName")
    public Mono<AccountsListResponse> getAccounts(String codeType) {
        return reactiveAccountsRepository.findByCodeType(codeType).map(this::convertToAccountsListResponse);
    }

    @Cacheable(value = "accounts", key = "#root.methodName")
    private AccountsListResponse convertToAccountsListResponse(Accounts accounts){
        return AccountsListResponse.builder().accounts(accounts.getCodeList().stream()
                                                                            .map(codes->AccountsResponse.builder().code(codes.getCode()).description(codes.getDescription())
                                                                            .build()).collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .build();
    }

}
```

ehcache.xml:

```
<config
        xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
        xmlns='http://www.ehcache.org/v3'
        xmlns:jsr107='http://www.ehcache.org/v3/jsr107'>

    <cache alias="accounts">
        <expiry>
            <none/>
        </expiry>
        <resources>
            <heap unit="entries">10000</heap>
        </resources>
    </cache>
</config>
```

Added this line to application.properties

```
#eh-cache
spring.cache.jcache.config=classpath:ehcache.xml
```

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableReactiveCouchbaseRepositories
@EnableCaching
public class AccountsApplication{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AccountsApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Pom dependencies:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
      <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
      <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I see the console and seems it is created:

> ```
> 2020-04-22 10:23:39.664  INFO 16512 --- [           main] org.ehcache.core.EhcacheManager          : 
> Cache 'accounts' created in EhcacheManager. 
> 2020-04-22 10:23:40.056  INFO 16512 --- [           main] org.ehcache.jsr107.Eh107CacheManager     : 
> Registering Ehcache MBean javax.cache:type=CacheStatistics,CacheManager=file./C./Proyectos/Core/core-accounts-boot/target/classes/ehcache.xml,Cache=accounts 
> 2020-04-22 10:23:40.064  INFO 16512 --- [           main] org.ehcache.jsr107.Eh107CacheManager     : 
> Registering Ehcache MBean javax.cache:type=CacheStatistics,CacheManager=file./C./Proyectos/Core/core-accounts-boot/target/classes/ehcache.xml,Cache=accounts
> ```

but when testing it always goes to the database to retrieve data. Am I missing something? Thank you !

Comment: Why are you using?  key = "#root.methodName"

Answer (score 3):

There may be few reasons .

1. In cache config try giving  tag as string and  as object since you are returning object , if you are returning list or map give that .
2. Make sure cache object is serialised .
3. If you are calling this service layer cached method from same class that is from AccountsServiceImpl then that cached method will be treated as a private method and annotations will be ignored .

Try calling this method from another class.

Comment: Ahh! implementing serializable. So obvious that I always forget it. Thanks!